# jQuery clone() not working

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a very simple jQuery `clone()` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#reset").click(function () {
        location.reload(); 
    });
    $("#clone").click(function () {
       //$('.hq').clone().insertAfter(".hq");
       $('.hq').clone().appendTo('.hq');
    }); 
</script>                        

 <div class="hq">
    <div class="textboxs">
         <select name="hq">
              <option value="-1">Select Headquarter</option>
                <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count( $get_hq_r ); $i++ ) { ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $get_hq_r[0]['id']; ?>"><?php echo $get_hq_r[$i]['name']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
         </select>    
    </div>
 </div>
<button id="clone">Add more</button> <button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

But when I click on the `Add more` button, insted of cloning the div, it refresh the page !

Comment: It seems are trying to bind the event handlers before the elements exist. Please have a look at http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/ to learn how to setup jQuery properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your `button` is inside of a form, so when clicked it will submit the form. You can stop it by using `event.preventDefault()` in your `click` handler:

```
$('#clone').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // your code
});
```